# JavaScript code not working in Firefox for ASPX web site

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have the following JS code that helps signing out a session from an ASPX page so a 'log out' record can be stored in a database. The code works when the site is opened with IE11, EDGE, and Chrome. Using those three browsers the user gets the popup asking if staying on the site or leaving the site. When it comes to be tested in Firefox, at least version 54, it just does not work. Nothings pops up.

Code is:

```
//We want to capture when a user logs out from the system - this is a way to force the browser to log out the session

window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode() {
    // when user clicks the 'X' from the browser, will be prompted to leave or to stay
    //clicking any of the options will trigger an event that will capture when the session was logged out and saved in the db
    var button = document.getElementById('btnLogout');
    button.click();
    return "You are closing or refreshing this site. Clicking 'Stay on this page' will log out your session. Clicking 'Leave this page' will close your window.";
    //return null;
}
//this will prevent the popup to appear everytime user navigates between pages/links 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[rel!=ext]').click(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
    $('form').submit(function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });
});
```

Comment: From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) "To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all." The browser compatibility indicates that Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari have some form of this quote, but it doesn't specify what the behavior is on each, possibly FF is just blocking the popup?

Comment: Also from the same MDN page "Note also, that various browsers ignore the result of the event and do not ask the user for confirmation at all. The document will always be unloaded automatically. Firefox has a switch named dom.disable_beforeunload in about:config to enable this behaviour."